# AVAjs - Plugin or preset file babel-preset-react/lib/index.js did not export a function

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, ava

I am trying to configure AVAjs with React.

So here is my AVA config inside package.json:

```
"ava": {
"files": [
  "test/**/*.spec.js"
],
"sources": [
  "**/*.{js,jsx}",
  "!dist/**/*"
],
"concurrency": 4,
"failFast": true,
"failWithoutAssertions": false,
"tap": true,
"compileEnhancements": false,
"require": [
  "@babel/core",
  "@babel/register",
  "@babel/polyfill"
],
"babel": {
  "testOptions": {
    "babelrc": false,
    "testOptions": {
      "presets": [
        ["@babel/preset-env", {
          "targets": {
            "node": "current"
          }
        }],
        ["@babel/preset-react", {
          "pragma": "dom",
          "pragmaFrag": "DomFrag",
          "throwIfNamespace": false
        }]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

}

And my test file:

```
import test from 'ava';
import React from 'react';
import Enzyme, { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import Other from '../assets/js/components/Other';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

test('has a .Foo class name', (t) => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Other />);
  t.pass(wrapper);
});
```

> Invalid:   `{ presets: [{option: value}] }` Valid:   `{ presets:
>   [['presetName', {option: value}]] }`

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using a 1.0 beta version of AVA. This uses Babel 7 (itself in beta) to compile your tests. However it's extending a Babel configuration that uses incompatible presets.

You should either upgrade your entire project to Babel 7 (which includes replacing `babel-register` and `babel-polyfill` by `@babel/register` and `@babel/polyfill`), or customize AVA's `testOptions` configuration to only use Babel 7 plugins (e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/preset-react).

Note that, if you opt for the latter approach, you'll have to set `"babelrc": false` to ensure AVA doesn't still include your Babel 6-compatible configuration.

Comment: I've update the babel imports to version 7 beta and I got another error. My question is updated.

Comment: Looks like a preset is wrongly configured. The `package.json` sample seems incorrect, you shouldn't test `testOptions`, but I don't think that'd lead to this error.